# Bedeutung von "was...alles"

Tags: meaning

> Was braucht unser Körper **alles** um gesund zu sein?
>
> Was er **alles** weiß!

Was hat es mit dem Wort "alles" auf sich? Hat der Satz dieselbe Bedeutung ohne das Wort oder nicht?

Comment: Disagree with the close vote, the proposed duplicate question is in English. As per the current [meta] votes, they should *both remain open*: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate and https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Stephie Hallo, ich hatte die Frage Off-Topic gevotet, nicht jedoch des Duplikats wegen. Meines Erachtens erfüllt die Frage nicht die Qualitätskriterien.

Comment: @Stephie, es mag sein, daß die Schließung des Duplikats wegen nicht korrekt ist, allerdings wurde diese vom OP selbst eingeleitet, dort ist ein Mouse-Hover über Community.